# Pandas Remove Duplicate Rows Based on Condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, duplicates

I have a pandas data frame as follows

```
+---------+------------+------------+-------+--------+
| Product |    Date    |  Adj_Date  | Price | Factor |
+---------+------------+------------+-------+--------+
| A       | 01-06-2020 | 01-07-2020 |   100 |     10 |
| A       | 01-06-2020 | 01-08-2020 |   200 |     20 |
| B       | 15-07-2020 | 01-07-2020 |   400 |     10 |
| B       | 15-07-2020 | 01-08-2020 |   800 |     10 |
| C       | 01-09-2020 | 01-07-2020 |  1000 |     10 |
| C       | 01-09-2020 | 01-08-2020 |  1200 |     10 |
| D       | 01-10-2020 | 01-11-2020 |  1400 |     10 |
| E       | 01-10-2020 | 01-09-2020 |  1600 |     10 |
+---------+------------+------------+-------+--------+
```

Code to generate the data frame above:

```
data = {'Product':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        'Date':['01-06-2020', '01-06-2020', '15-07-2020', '15-07-2020', '01-09-2020', '01-09-2020', '01-10-2020', '01-10-2020'],
        'Adj_Date':['01-07-2020', '01-08-2020', '01-07-2020', '01-08-2020', '01-07-2020', '01-08-2020', '01-11-2020', '01-09-2020'],
        'Price':[100, 200, 400, 800, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1600],
        'Factor':[10,20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]}
df =pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Desired Output:

```
+---------+------------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+
| Product |    Date    |  Adj_Date  | Price | Factor | Actual Price |
+---------+------------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+
| A       | 01-06-2020 | 01-07-2020 |   100 |     10 |           10 |
| B       | 15-07-2020 | 01-08-2020 |   800 |     10 |           80 |
| C       | 01-09-2020 | 01-07-2020 |  1000 |     10 |         1000 |
| D       | 01-10-2020 | 01-11-2020 |  1400 |     10 |          140 |
| E       | 01-10-2020 | 01-09-2020 |  1600 |     10 |         1600 |
+---------+------------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+
```

The above result is based on comparing 2 columns `Date` and `Adj_Date`. If for any product there are 2 rows we choose row in which `Date` is less than `Adj_Date` and differnce between `Adj_Date` is minimum. As we can see for product A we have `date = 01-06-2020` this date was less than `Adj_Date` in both the rows but we choose `Adj_Date = 01-07-2020` as the difference with this date is minimum. Using the same logic we opt for row 2 in case of product B.
If `Date` is greater than `Adj_Date` in all cases than we keep the first row.

Next part is to create column `Actual Price`. Once we have single row for each product we divide `Price` with `Factor` to create `Actual Price` only if `Date` is less than `Adj_Date`. Else `Actual Price` is equal to `Price`.

How can this result be achieved?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far. We can assist you better that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convert `Date` and `Adj_Date` to Timestamp. This will make your life a lot easier:

```
for col in ['Date', 'Adj_Date']:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], dayfirst=True)
```

Then:

```
# Pick one row for each product
def pick_one(group):
    if len(group) == 1:
        return group

    diff = (group['Date'] - group['Adj_Date']).dt.days
    if (diff < 0).any():
        cond = group.index == diff[diff < 0].idxmax()
    else:
        cond = group.index == group.index[0]

    return group.loc[cond]

result = df.groupby('Product', as_index=False).apply(pick_one).droplevel(0)

# Calculate the Actual Price
result['Actual Price'] = np.where(result['Date'] < result['Adj_Date'], result['Price'] / result['Factor'], result['Price'])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `duplicated` and `groupby.idxmin` to filter your dataframe, then apply a boolean to get your `ActualPrice` column.

```
import numpy as np
# ensure you have valid datetime objects.
#df[['Date','Adj_Date']] = df[['Date','Adj_Date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df1 = df.loc[
    df.assign(
        delta=np.where(
            df.duplicated(subset=["Product"], keep=False),
            (df["Date"] - df["Adj_Date"]).abs(),
            0,
        )
    )
    .groupby("Product")["delta"]
    .idxmin()
]
```

---

```
df1['ActualPrice'] = np.where(
    df1['Date'] <= df1['Adj_Date'],
    df1['Price'].div(df1['Factor']),
    df1['Price']
)
```

---

```
print(df1)

  Product       Date   Adj_Date  Price  Factor  ActualPrice
0       A 2020-01-06 2020-01-07    100      10         10.0
3       B 2020-07-15 2020-01-08    800      10        800.0
5       C 2020-01-09 2020-01-08   1200      10       1200.0
6       D 2020-01-10 2020-01-11   1400      10        140.0
7       E 2020-01-10 2020-01-09   1600      10       1600.0
```